# Sum values in binary tree of integers weighted by depth

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

Here is my reference tree:

```
    3
   / \
  5   2
 /   / \
1   4   6
```

Here is the expected output of the recursive method:

```
(1*3) + (2 * (5 + 2)) + (3 * (1 + 4 + 6)) = 50
```

...and here is the code I have thus far:

```
public int depthSum()
{
    int depth = 1;
    return depthSum(overallRoot, depth);
}

public int depthSum(IntTreeNode someNode, int someDepth)
{
    if(someNode == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return someDepth * someNode.data + //some recursion
    }
}
```

I get that I have to likely call myself and increment someDepth, but I can't seem to get this right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you mean:

```
return someDepth * someNode.data +
       depthSum(someNode.left, someDepth+1) +
       depthSum(someNode.right, someDepth+1);
```

Comment: I was convinced I had to do something like (depth+1 * depthSum(someNode.left, someDepth+1) ...